# How to find length of query in slick and use it as a boolean?

Tags: scala, slick

We are using Slick. We have a table which has some entries, I have a key which I want to use to query the table. I only need a boolean value to know whether that key exists in the table in some column Y.

I know the key, I know Y . But Slick is really having me bang my head to the wall.

This is my current approach :

```
val query = EventInfo.filter(_.id === 32323).map(u=>u.id).exists
val action = query.result
val results  = db.run( action)
results.onComplete(println)
```

It does print : Success(true)

But I want to use this boolean value inside the procedure to call method A if true and method B if false.

I can't understand how to extract this value to a variable and then use it inside onComplete function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest fix is

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

try {
  Await.result({
    results.map { 
      case true => println("method A")
      case false => println("method B")
    }
  }, 1 minute)
} finally db.close()
```